# How to stop two function to run at the same time in if If statements python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the script below, my issue is that in the if statement both function run at the same time.
when I click on Celcuis i need only "temperature" to run and when I click fahrenheit to run "temperature2 "

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


root = Tk()
root.title('Raspberry Temperature')
root.geometry("250x250")

lab = Label(root)
lab.pack(pady=10)
lab.place(x=150, y=15)

label1 = Label(root, text="Core Temperature :", font=('Segoe', 10))
label1.pack(pady=10)
label1.place(x=20, y=15)

lab2 = Label(root)
lab2.pack(pady=10)
lab2.place(x=140, y=15)

def temperature():
    lab2.delete(1.0, END)
    lab.config(text=100, font=('Segoe', 11, 'bold'))

def temperature2():
    lab.text.delete(1.0, END)
    lab2.config(text=2, font=('Segoe', 11, 'bold'))

OptionList = [
"Celsius",
"Fahrenheit ",
"kelvin",
]

variable = tk.StringVar(root)
variable.set(OptionList[0])

opt = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable, *OptionList)
opt.config(width=5, font=('Helvetica', 8))
opt.pack(side="right")

def callback(*args):
    s = variable.get()
    if s == "Celsius":
        temperature()
    elif s == "Fahrenheit ":
        temperature2()
variable.trace("w", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's not possible. When you have `if/elif`, only one of them will ever run.

Comment: The code posted doesn't behave the way you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems with your code seems to be `lab.text.delete` `delete` is not a valid method for the Tkinter label and instead you can simply use `lab.config(text="")` to remove any content.

For your optionMenu you can add a `command` argument when creating it so whenever the user clicks one of the options in the optionmenu it calls a function and passes the selected option as a string, for example

```py
def myFunction(event):
    print(event)

opVar=StringVar()
options=["A","B","C"]
opt=OptionMenu(root,opVar,*options,command=myFunction)
```

You can then use this ability in your program and create an if statement for every item in your `optionList` as follows...

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


root = Tk()
root.title('Raspberry Temperature')
root.geometry("250x250")

lab = Label(root)
lab.pack(pady=10)
lab.place(x=150, y=15)

label1 = Label(root, text="Core Temperature :", font=('Segoe', 10))
label1.pack(pady=10)
label1.place(x=20, y=15)

lab2 = Label(root)
lab2.pack(pady=10)
lab2.place(x=140, y=15)

def temperature():
    lab2.config(text="")
    lab.config(text=100, font=('Segoe', 11, 'bold'))

def temperature2():
    lab.config(text="")
    lab2.config(text=2, font=('Segoe', 11, 'bold'))


def loadOption(event):
    if event == OptionList[0]:
        temperature()
    elif event == OptionList[1]:
        temperature2()
    else:
        print("Unrecognised Input")
        
OptionList = [
"Celsius",
"Fahrenheit ",
"kelvin",
]

variable = tk.StringVar(root)
variable.set("Celsius")

opt = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable,*OptionList,command=loadOption)
opt.config(width=15, font=('Helvetica', 8))
opt.pack(side="right")

#Load on startup
loadOption("Celsius")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me. You just have to modify this part and the errors will vanish.

```
def temperature():
    lab2.config(text="", font=('Segoe', 11, 'bold'))
    lab.config(text=100, font=('Segoe', 11, 'bold'))

def temperature2():
    lab.config(text="", font=('Segoe', 11, 'bold'))
    lab2.config(text=2, font=('Segoe', 11, 'bold'))
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, so that OP can learn from it.